# A word for something is being processed

Tags: word-request

When a process is done over a series of things (e.g series of nodes of a graph), they may be in turn processed. What are words for the node that is being processed?

- Current Node
- Under-Process Node ?!
- Under Consideration
- ...

It is a general question, "node" is just an example here

Comment: Wrong SE site! Perhaps [**this**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is where the question belongs.

Comment: @P.E.Dant it is a general question, "node" is just an example here.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you are looking for a word similar to "ongoing"

Comment: Your first choice, **current**, is fine. You don't need to find a more specific word since you've established the context: you are processing each member of the set in turn, and the member being processed at any given moment is the "current" one.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, I also suggested "Under consideration"... are "under process" or "under consideration" valid phrases?

Comment: Under process, no.  Under consideration, possibly.

Comment: The clearest thing you can say is likely "current node being processed" or "node currently being processed."

Comment: @Ahmad.  You should create a sample sentence. Your question is awfully broad as is.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to indicate this

> Current node being processed is *"X"*
>   Node being processed is *"X"*
>   Processing node *"X"*
>   Currently on *"X"*

Basically, almost any combination of "currently", "processing", "node", and "X" will work.